# How to store an array that is within an another array to a global variable that has been passed from JSON in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I have a JSON which receives an array from an API call

Within that array are 3 other arrays:

`userDetails`, `userStats`, `communities`

An example of this API call is:

```
["communities": <__NSArrayI 0x6000002540a0>(
{
id = 5;
name = South;
},
{
id = 13;
name = HurraHarry;
},
{
id = 15;
name = EnclliffeT;
}
)
, "userStats": {
totalDraws = 3;
totalLosses = 10;
totalWins = 1;
}, "userDetails": {
id = 31;
"user_email" = "steve@gmail.com";
"user_name" = "Steve Base";
}]
```

I would like to store the array `userStats` in a variable that I can pass to another VC.

I have a global variable `var userStatsArray = [AnyObject]()` in my class

and the following code deals with the JSON:

```
 let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                  print (json!)

                  if let arr = json?["communities"] as? [[String:String]] {
                        self.communitiesArray = arr.flatMap { $0["name"]!}
                        self.communityIdsArray = arr.flatMap { $0["id"]!}

                    }

                    if let dict = json?["userDetails"] as? [String:String] {
                      self.tempPlayerId = [dict["id"]!]
                        let characterArray = self.tempPlayerId.flatMap { String.CharacterView($0) }
                        let newPlayerId = String(characterArray)
                        self.playerId = newPlayerId
                    }
                    if  let tempArray = json?["userStats"] as? [String:AnyObject]{
                        print ("here ", tempArray)

                    }
```

The print command successfully prints the `userStats` array with all its headers (totalWins, totalDraws, totalLosses...) -

How do I store this array into my global variable `var userStatsArray = [AnyObject]()` so I can pass it to another VC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you create one custom class like this, and declare the array with that custom class type. then you cast your userStats object to your custom class type.

```
class userStats: NSObject {

var totalDraws: NSNumber?
var totalLosses: NSNumber?
var totalWins: NSNumber?

    init(totalDraws: NSNumber?, totalLosses: NSNumber?, totalWins: NSNumber?) {
        self.totalDraws = totalDraws
        self.totalWins = totalWins
        self.totalLosses = totalLosses
    }

}

var userStatsArray = [userStats]()
```

// CHANGE YOUR CODE LIKE THIS

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
              print (json!)

              if let arr = json?["communities"] as? [[String:String]] {
                    self.communitiesArray = arr.flatMap { $0["name"]!}
                    self.communityIdsArray = arr.flatMap { $0["id"]!}

                }

                if let dict = json?["userDetails"] as? [String:String] {
                  self.tempPlayerId = [dict["id"]!]
                    let characterArray = self.tempPlayerId.flatMap { String.CharacterView($0) }
                    let newPlayerId = String(characterArray)
                    self.playerId = newPlayerId
                }
                if  let tempArray = json?["userStats"]as? userStats {

                    userSytatsArray.append(tempArray)
                }
```

Comment: So would the array `userStatsArray` be fine to be then passed across via segue and the contents would be set up as defined in the class userStats?

Comment: you can pass userStatsArray to where ever you want, by declaring same type of array in destination view controller.

Comment: Why do you declare optional properties but only a non-optional initializer in the custom class? Consider that in a class a declared initializer must be used.

Comment: @vadian initializer changed as optional :)

Comment: @RDowns, please use class initializer as optional one, see updated initializer method in userStats class.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ObjectMapper](https://cocoapods.org/pods/ObjectMapper/%22ObjectMapper%22)! With that powerful framework you can create the mappable models of your data returned by the API and let it perform the whole work for you :)

Declare your model classes like this:

```
class UserInfo: Mappable {
var communities : [Community]?
var stats: UserStats?
var details: UserDetails?

required init?(map: Map) {
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    communities <- map["communities"]
    stats <- map["userStats"]
    details <- map["userDetails"]
 }
}

class Community: Mappable {
var id: Int!
var name: String!

required init?(map: Map) {
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["id"]
    name <- map["name"]
 }
}

class UserStats: Mappable {
var totalDraws : Int!
var totalLosses : Int!
var totalWins : Int!

required init?(map: Map) {
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    totalDraws <- map["totalDraws"]
    totalLosses <- map["totalLosses"]
    totalWins <- map["totalWins"]
 }
}

class UserDetails: Mappable {
var id : Int!
var email : String!
var username : String!

required init?(map: Map) {
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["id"]
    email <- map["user_email"]
    username <- map["user_name"]
 }
}
```

And later just:

```
let user = UserInfo(JSONString: JSONString)
```